# Polymorphism read from file

Tags: c++, polymorphism, istream, ostream

If I'm writing classes derived from a parent class to file, how do I determine which class I am reading in from file?

Basically I have 3 derived classes: `DerivedA`, `DerivedB`, `DerivedC`. When writing to the file I have done this:

> ```
> DerivedA
>    attribute1
>    attribute2
>    attribute9
> DerivedB
>    attribute5
>    attribute6
> DerivedC
>    attribute4
>    attribute7
> ```

How do I set my if statements up to determine which class I am reading in at the moment?

EDIT:

I am building a list of homes with specific different attributes to each home.

```
list<Homes*> home;
Homes *tmp;
while(ins>>tmp)
{//determine which home it is
  tmp=new ***//depends on which derived class it is;
}
```

In my data file it will say:

```
Brickhome
solar panels
3 bathrooms
Spiral Staircase
LogCabin
gravel driveway
fireplace
Castle
10 butlers
1 moat
```

I need a way of determining which home needs to be created.

Comment: Can you provide some actual sample code to help illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: Added to original post, thank you

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what the attributes could be?  The sample code you included doesn't really have much to do with the part you actually have a question about.

Comment: Just added some more about the attributes, although the line break didn't work correctly. I'm going to try to do it again

Comment: Is the derived class determined by `Brickhome`, `LogCabin`, or `Castle`?  Or better yet, do you have to store the data in this manner and have your classes set up in this way?  I can imagine some better methods.

Comment: Yes, those are the derived classes. I need to do this by polymorphism, and I need to write everything to file, and read it from file. I'm just lost as how to determine which class I'm actually dealing with before I read it in.

Comment: I suppose something like `if (dynamic_cast<type_of_house>(tmp))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know which derived type to construct before you read the line that names it. What you *can* do is have a function that reads the first line, then delegates the rest to the appropriate subclass constructor.

```
list<Homes*> home;
string str;
while(ins >> str)
{
  switch(str)
  {
    Homes *tmp;

    case "Brickhome":
      tmp = new Brickhome(ins);
      break;
    case "LogCabin":
      tmp = new LogCabin(ins);
      break;
    case "Castle":
      tmp = new Castle(ins);
      break;
    default:
      throw("unknown type of home");
  }
  home.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Note that the subclasses must have a sensible way of knowing when to stop (e.g. `Brickhome` must either know how many attributes it has, or know that "LogCabin" cannot be one of its attributes, and must therefore be put back into the stream before the constructor terminates).